python list comprehension -- two loops with three results?
I can ask my question best by just giving an example.  Let's say I want to use a list comprehension to generate a set of 3-element tuples from two loops, something like this:
[ (y+z,y,z) for y in range(10) if y%2==0 for z in range(20) if z%3==0 ]

This works, giving me
[(0, 0, 0), (3, 0, 3), (6, 0, 6), (9, 0, 9), (12, 0, 12), (15, 0, 15), ... ]

I am wondering, though, if there is a way to do it more cleanly, something to the effect of
[ (x,y,z) for y in range(10) if y%2==0 for z in range(20) if z%3==0 ... somehow defining x(y,z) ... ]

I would consider something like this to be more clean, especially since what I really need to do is much more complicated than the example I give here.  Everything I have tried has given me a syntax error.

There is no magic here.  If there are two loop variables, then your tuple needs to be expressed in terms of those two loop variables.  You can't have a variable somehow magically alter itself based on other variables.  And BTW, the less "magic" solution is the cleaner solution.

You can do:
out = [
    (x, y, z)
    for y in range(10)
    if y % 2 == 0
    for z in range(20)
    if z % 3 == 0
    for x in [y + z]  # <-- initialize `x` in list-comprehension
]

This is optimized since Python 3.9: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.9.html#optimizations

Thanks!  Just what I needed.  (And the one thing it didn't occur to me to try!)

Even with the optimization this is 3x slower than chepners, and significantly less readable.

@wim Because chepner's pretends that the question's MRE is the OP's actual case rather than just an MRE, and does simplifications specific to that example that don't apply in general.

To be clear, at least in the OP's simplified example, the original (y+z, y, z) is the better solution. There's no reason to initialize another variable that exists solely to then be loaded for the result, optimized or not. Even if readability is a concern, the produced tuple itself could be split across lines the same way as the unnecessary extra for loop, to have a single element per line. The main reason to use this construct is if you are both testing and producing the value (e.g. the listcomp ends with if x % 5 == 0 and it is also producing x in the result tuple).

@ShadowRanger "There's no reason" - The reason is stated in the question. The OP "would consider something like this to be more clean, especially since what I really need to do is much more complicated than the example I give here". And I do agree that seeing a list comp that starts with a nice [(x, y, z) for ... immediately makes it clear what kind of elements the list will contain, unlike with something "much more complicated" than y + z. It's similar to ending a function with two statements x = <complicated> and return x, y, z instead of one return <complicated>, y, z.

@nocomment: Yeah, that's where the second part of my comment comes in. The complexity will be there, no matter what. Split up the tuple itself across lines, and you get the same result (complexity isolated on a line by itself) without the weird-looking hack. If it's complex enough, you skip the listcomp entirely and can do exactly what you suggest, either factoring out to a generator function or just hand-writing a loop with manual append calls (either of which makes it trivial to do x = <complicated> separately). If your listcomp is really that complex, skip the listcomp.

Sadly can't demonstrate what I mean directly in a comment (because newlines are lost), but are you really arguing that adding an extra artificial for over a one-off one-element list for this purpose is meaningfully cleaner than adding an artificial newline to the tuple so you get (<complicated>, on one line, then y,, then z) on separate lines?

@ShadowRanger I do think that seeing the name x and the triple of names (x, y, z) is beneficial. Instantly recognizable as 3D-coordinates rather than some mysterious something and a y and a z. Whether it outweighs the disadvantage of that for depends on the actual case and context and the reader.

I would skip the division and just generate the desired multiples explicitly.
[(y+z,y,z) for y in range(0, 10, 2) for z in range(0, 20, 3)]

Now you can use itertools.product instead of two generators.
[(sum(p), *p) for p in product(range(0, 10, 2), range(0, 20, 3))]


There is no reason to do this in the scenario described no matter how complex the expression being named is. If the expression is complicated, just break up the tuple definition:
[(y+z,  # Doesn't matter if this is complex; by using one element per line, it's clear
        # the complexity doesn't interfere with interpreting the rest of the listcomp
  y,
  z)
 for y in range(10)
 if y%2==0
 for z in range(20) 
 if z%3==0]

If you actually both test and produce the value (so it must be assigned to a name), sure, use Andrej's solution, and do:
[(x, y, z)       # Produce here, having computed x only once
 for y in range(10)
 if y%2==0
 for z in range(20) 
 if z%3==0
 for x in [y+z]  # Substitute complex expression here
 if x%5==0       # Test here
]

or if you don't care about x leaking from the listcomp's scope, the even simpler/more concise walrus-based (:=) approach:
[(x, y, z)       # Produce here, having computed x only once
 for y in range(10)
 if y%2==0
 for z in range(20) 
 if z%3==0 and (x := y+z)%5==0  # Test and assign to x here
]

But when you only need the value once, there's not much to be gained from naming it unless you have a really good name to give it for clarity (and I'd argue that defining a simple named tuple for the produced values might be the way to go in that case, rather than only giving it a useful name inside the listcomp).
If the expression is complex enough to justify more than this, it's complex enough that you should probably just drop the listcomp in favor of a manual expansion of it to a for loop, e.g.:
result = []
for y in range(10):
    if y%2 == 0:
        for z in range(20):
            if z%3 == 0:
                x = y + z  # You can do the complex expression here, possibly breaking it up
                           # into multiple lines itself for clarity
                result.append((x, y, z))

or factoring it out to a generator function:
def do_whatever():
    for y in range(10):
        if y%2 == 0:
            for z in range(20):
                if z%3 == 0:
                    x = y + z  # You can do the complex expression here, possibly breaking it up
                               # into multiple lines itself for clarity
                    yield (x, y, z)

that you can invoke with do_whatever() (list(do_whatever()) to collect the results to a list immediately if you can't just iterate them one by one for processing).
